# activerecord update wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Sorry if this is a simple problem that has been explained before. I've done some research about my problem. I'm completely new to ruby and active record and I find the examples other have had with the wrong number of arguments too complicated for me to follow. So here is my simple one.

I'm trying to do a simple update using activerecord to a db. All I'm trying to do add a value to the title attribute that I left as nil when I created it in the first place.

vertigo is the variable I assigned using the `.find` method.

I'm typing in `vertigo.update(title: 'Vertigo')`

But I'm getting an error message saying

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2).
```

Here is more of session. I'm using Sinatra-tux >> vertigo = Movie.all
D, [2015-04-20T11:11:38.890714 #3741] DEBUG -- :   Movie Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"
=> #]>

> > vertigo.update title: "Vertigo"
> >     ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
> >         /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:330:in `update'
> >         (ripl):4:in`'

Comment: can you post all your entire update. Include your variable assignment. It should be working. What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**find** can return an array. It's entirely possible that your *vertigo* variable is actually an array.

Try to run

```
vertigo[0].update(title: 'Vertigo')
```

assuming you only want to change the first one.

Comment: I just ran into this. You can also use `.first` -- `vertigo.first.update(title: 'Vertigo')`